# jQuery vs DOM performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have written this code to benchmark jQuery vs DOM performance. The performance is defferent in every browser with the worst performer Firefox X25 slower running jQuery.
Is this expected behavior? I wasn't expecting to see such an impact with jQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var i=0;
    var dtb = new Date();
    while(i < 1000000)
    {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*30);
        i++;
        var elem = document.getElementById('d'+index);
    }
    var dte = new Date();
    alert(dte-dtb);

    i=0;
    var dtb2 = new Date();
    var body = document.getElementById('cog');
    while(i < 1000000)
    {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*30);
        i++;
        var elem = body.childNodes[index];
    }
    var dte2 = new Date();
    alert(dte2-dtb2);

    i=0;
    var dtb3 = new Date();
    while(i < 1000000)
    {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*30);
        i++;
        var $elem = $("#d"+index);
    }
    var dte3 = new Date();
    alert(dte3-dtb3);



    /////EDIT//////
    ///// Implemented an Array as suggested by Erik Reppen  ////////


    i = 0;
    var idNames=new Array(30);
    while(i<30){
        idNames[i] = $("#d"+i);
        i++;
    }


    i=0;
    var dtb4 = new Date();
    while(i < 1000000)
    {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*30);
        i++;
        var $elem = idNames[index];
    }
    var dte4 = new Date();
    alert(dte4-dtb4);

    /////EDIT//////////////////////////////////////////////



});

</script>
</head>

<body id="cog">
<div id="d0">sdfkjjfgdfd@@@</div><div id="d1">sdffgdfd@@@</div><div id="d2">sddfgfd</div><div id="d3">sdasfd</div><div id="d4">swqedfd</div><div id="d5">sddfdsfd</div><div id="d6">sdfd</div><div id="d7">sdsdffd</div><div id="d8">sdfsdfd</div><div id="d9">sdfkjlkjd</div><div id="d10">sdm ,nfd</div><div id="d11">sdcxvfd</div><div id="d12">sdxzcmfd</div><div id="d13">shgjmdfd</div><div id="d14">sdfvcbd</div><div id="d15">sdf;k;d</div><div id="d16">sdjklfd</div><div id="d17">sd412fd</div><div id="d18">sdfkyhkd</div><div id="d19">sdasdfd</div><div id="d20">sdhdfgsfd</div><div id="d21">sdfdsad</div><div id="d22">sdasdfd</div><div id="d23">sddfgdffd</div><div id="d24">sdklugiffd</div><div id="d25">sddfsafd</div><div id="d26">sdfq21fd</div><div id="d27">42324sdfd</div><div id="d28">sdnhmjkgufksfd</div><div id="d29">sdqwefdLAST</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI: jQuery itself is doing DOM manipulation.

Comment: jQuery does a lot more than DOM manipulation when someone may expect to do just DOM manupulation. This may affect the performances.
To the author: check if your benchmark is valuable comparing it to some other common test tools, like http://jsperf.com/

Comment: I would do more to cache operations since these are really huge loops. Cache all your IDs into an array before the first loop so that your loop just hits the array rather than concatenating a string before accessing getElementById. Then cache body.childNodes in a var before the next loop. IE in particular is very slow at DOM access which involves a buildup/teardown process. For JQ I would do a similar loop to childNodes but cache $('body').children() and then just cachedChildren[index] inside the loop (unless you'd rather have JQuery instances of each child rather than regular dom objects).

Comment: Eh, screw it, I added some snippits for the above to my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This:

```
$('#someId');
```

ultimately boils down to the JQuery function saying

```
document.getElementId('someId'); // and then wrap it in a JQuery object and return it
```

But first, it has to do a bunch of logic to figure out what your intentions are based on the arg you sent. Something like (and I know there's much more than this):

Is it a string? Yes. Are there spaces? No. Does it start with '#', '.', or some valid tagName? It starts with '#'. Great, just grab by ID, package and return it.

Now try doing a test on this:

```
$('#someId.active > .someClass:visible')
```

Vs. whatever ungodly mess you have to write for the DOM in IE7 and you'll see the whole point of JQuery.

Generally speaking, repeating DOM selections over and over again is kind of a silly thing to do regardless of whether you're using core DOM methods or especially JQuery. It's like griping about function call overhead when no functions are getting used inside loops. Try comparing some DOM methods and JQ equivalents after caching that initial element grab instead. JQ might still be slower but I doubt 25 times slower in anything.

```
var $_someId = $('#someId');
dom_someId = document.getElementById('someId');
//now try looping a JQuery method vs an equivalent set of DOM methods for each
```

===Unrelated but helping with original test===

Here's some examples per comments below and back up at your question as far as stuff to do before the loop.

```
//caching ID names before loop
var i = 30,
idNames = [];
while(i--){ //confusing but tests as i, then inside i is i-=1
idNames[i] = 'd'+(i+1);
}
```

Note: You index the array by 0-30 so kill the +1 after the random index building statement in the loop. In fact I'm not sure why that 1-31 doesn't blow up your childNodes loop since it never hits the first element and should be trying to access two that aren't there.Remove the +1 and it's picking 0-30. The above loop assumed you wanted 1-31 but I just saw that the HTML only goes up to the 30 and starts with 1.

```
//caching object/property lookup and DOM Access/HTMLCollection/obj instantiation
var bodyChildren = body.childNodes; //DOM object lookups cost performance

//caching JQ so you can use the exact same loop afterwards
var bodyChildren = $('body').children();

//inside loops
bodyChildren[index];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was actually comparing DOM getElementById vs childNodes, but then decided to compare both to jQuery and got surprised by the result and posted the question. The DOM selection test is actually what was important for me to test because the application will have to do the same and it should be ultra-fast. I have decided to use getElementById, this is mainly due to IE being too slow with childNodes.

Comment: For a more fair comparison of getElementById to childNodes, you might want build a lookup table for all those IDs since under typical circumstances you would be passing a string without the string concatenation step. There's also a process every time you do a property lookup, especially a DOM-related one so assign body.childNodes to a var before the loop.

Comment: Thanks Erik! I have updated the OP and included the Array solution suggested by you and also switched the accepted answer because you provided an actual solution. Thanks again for all the support!

Answer (score 5):

jQuery is a wrapper that normalizes DOM manipulation in a way that works consistently in every major browser. It's fully reasonable for it to perform 25x slower than direct DOM manipulation. The performance loss is a tradeoff to have concise code.

JavaScript in general is a highly asynchronous language. Much of its usage involves waiting for a user-triggered callback, or timer. Because there's so much time, performance is hardly ever an issue. A user wont notice the difference between a process that runs in 1ms compared to a process that runs in 25ms.

If there *is* a significant performance hit in one of your scripts, use tools to analyze where the code is taking the most time.

After all, premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: I thought it was the love of premature optimisation that is the root of all evil...

Comment: I am studying DOM and I got a suggestion to better work on jquery in order land to first job in front-end asap.

Answer (score 4):

This is because `$("#d"+index);` does not do the same thing as `document.getElementById('d'+index);`. The latter gets a DOM object. This is a native type of object, built into the browser.

`$`, however, builds a jQuery object. First, it has to parse the selector, since jQuery can find things by class, attribute, ancestor, etc., whereas `document.getElementById` only finds elements by their ID. The jQuery object is not a native object, so is slower to create, and it also has much more potential. For instance, the jQuery object (which actually is a wrapper around the native DOM objects) provides the `next`, `val`, `bind` and `on` methods. Doing the selection (or at least, doing a selection this simple) is slower with jQuery than with native DOM objects, but makes programming with it easier and often makes the execution faster, since the authors of jQuery are probably better at Javascript than you.

Answer (score 1):

You're using jQuery like a sledgehammer to kill a mosquito. Everytime you do `$("#d"+index)`, you tell jQuery to parse your selector, apply the selector to the DOM, then wrap the result in a memory-consuming object. This is really time consuming.

Morale: use jQuery when you need to, and performances aren't the leit motif of your function.